# How to export/import .NET Users (SqlProvider) from one IIS website to another

Tags: iis, website, .net, export, migration

How do I, or is it even possible to, export .NET Users (signed up using a SqlProvider) from one IIS website and import them into a separate IIS website.

I realize there's quite a few database tables that must be accounted for and keys that must match, which is also why I'd prefer if there was an "official" way to do this.

Yes I know I can re-create the users manually but it's a time consuming task.

I'm using IIS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an ASP website that created the default aspnetdb database, stop the SQL server service on the old server, detach the database, copy it to the new server, attach it to the new SQL instance that you have running on the server. You will then need to update your web.config file in the site to point to the appropriate new SQL server instance. AFAIK, there isn't any server specific ID's in those tables. Just application/user/role specific ID's.